# SQL code for extracting and averaging day end values across multiple clients

Tags: mysql, average

I have data organized by

- date,time
- client_id
- transaction_id
- transaction value

A client can have multiple transactions per day at different times. I would like to:

1. extract the last value of the day for each client. This is specified by the last transaction_id for the client for the day
2. Sum up all the values in 1 for each day
3. Calculate the average of all values in 2

I cannot figure out the SQL code to do this. A dummy dataset is attached. Please can someone assist? I am looking for SQL script that will yield the value 1116 in the example below. Thank you

| SOURCE DATA |  |  |  | **CALCULATIONS** | **** | **** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date, Time | Client_id | Transaction_id | Value | **Extracted value** | **Sum for the day** | **Average of sums** |
| DATE 1, TIME 1 | A | 1 | 123 |  | 1078 | 1105 |
| DATE 1, TIME 2 | A | 2 | 230 |  |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 3 | A | 3 | 233 | 233 |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 4 | B | 4 | 179 |  |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 5 | B | 5 | 263 | 263 |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 6 | C | 6 | 136 |  |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 7 | C | 7 | 116 |  |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 8 | C | 8 | 296 |  |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 9 | C | 9 | 126 | 126 |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 10 | D | 10 | 100 |  |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 11 | D | 11 | 198 | 198 |  |  |
| DATE 1, TIME 12 | F | 12 | 258 | 258 |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 13 | A | 13 | 224 |  | 1132 |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 14 | A | 14 | 104 | 104 |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 15 | B | 15 | 187 |  |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 16 | B | 16 | 118 |  |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 17 | B | 17 | 248 |  |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 18 | B | 18 | 185 | 185 |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 19 | C | 19 | 291 | 291 |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 20 | E | 20 | 292 | 292 |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 21 | G | 21 | 276 |  |  |  |
| DATE 2, TIME 22 | G | 22 | 260 | 260 |  |  |

Comment: Is 'DATE 1, TIME 1' really the value of column 'Date, Time'? Could you please provide the CREATE TABLE statement for your table?

Comment: No Date 1, Time 1 is just a dummy value. All values on the sample table are dummy values. The actual  table is result of joining numerous tables. Is CREATE TABLE the code that relates to that?

Comment: We need the schema of this table, e. g. the query would look different if `Date, Time` consists of characters, is of type DATETIME  or means in fact two columns, e. g. DATE and TIME.

Comment: Hi. Date and time are in a single column with the following format
'2022-01-06 10:22:32'

Comment: Vimal, shouldn't the extracted value for transaction 11 be 198 and for transaction 14 be 104? If so, please edit your post.

Comment: Apologies @Mihe. You are correct. I have edited the post and updated sums and average accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `source_data` (
  `Date, Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Client_id` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transaction_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value` int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `source_data` VALUES
  ('2022-07-01 00:01:00', 'A', 1, 123),
  ('2022-07-01 00:01:05', 'A', 2, 230),
  ('2022-07-01 00:01:10', 'A', 3, 233),
  ('2022-07-01 00:02:00', 'B', 4, 179),
  ('2022-07-01 00:02:05', 'B', 5, 263),
  ('2022-07-01 00:03:00', 'C', 6, 136),
  ('2022-07-01 00:03:05', 'C', 7, 116),
  ('2022-07-01 00:03:10', 'C', 8, 296),
  ('2022-07-01 00:03:10', 'C', 9, 126),
  ('2022-07-01 00:04:00', 'D', 10, 100),
  ('2022-07-01 00:04:05', 'D', 11, 198),
  ('2022-07-01 00:06:00', 'F', 12, 258),
  ('2022-07-02 00:01:00', 'A', 13, 224),
  ('2022-07-02 00:01:05', 'A', 14, 104),
  ('2022-07-02 00:02:00', 'B', 15, 187),
  ('2022-07-02 00:02:05', 'B', 16, 118),
  ('2022-07-02 00:02:10', 'B', 17, 248),
  ('2022-07-02 00:02:15', 'B', 18, 185),
  ('2022-07-02 00:03:00', 'C', 19, 291),
  ('2022-07-02 00:05:00', 'E', 20, 292),
  ('2022-07-02 00:07:00', 'G', 21, 276),
  ('2022-07-02 00:07:05', 'G', 22, 260);
```

Query:

```
WITH last_tx_values_per_day AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      date(`Date, Time`) as `Date`,
      `Client_id`, 
      first_value(`Value`) OVER (
          PARTITION BY date(`Date, Time`), `Client_id`
          ORDER BY `Transaction_id` DESC) AS last_tx_value
  FROM `source_data`
),
daily_sums AS (
  SELECT `Date`, sum(last_tx_value) AS sum_per_day
  FROM last_tx_values_per_day
  GROUP BY `Date`
)
SELECT avg(sum_per_day) AS `Average of daily sums`
  FROM daily_sums;
```

Apart from the first CTE, it should be pretty self-explanatory.

The CTE `last_tx_values_per_day` uses the first_value window function to get the last transaction value. Here, a window partitioned by date (the date-part of the datetime field) and the ID of the client is used.

To get the value of the last transaction, the records in the window will be ordered by transaction id, but in a descending order. Therefore, the first record in the window is the one with the highest transaction id. That is, the window function results in the value of the last transaction.

The CTE `daily_sums` just sums things up for each day, so that the average can be taken, finally.

**Update**

As the OP uses MySQL 5.7, which doesn't support CTEs and window functions, the following should work:

```
SELECT avg(sum_per_day) AS `Average of daily sums`
  FROM (SELECT sum(`Value`) AS sum_per_day
          FROM `source_data` s 
         WHERE `Transaction_id` = (
                 SELECT max(`Transaction_id`) 
                   FROM `source_data` 
                  WHERE date(`Date, Time`) = date(s.`Date, Time`)
                    AND client_id = s.client_id
               )
         GROUP BY date(`Date, Time`)
        ) daily_sums;
```

Comment: Hey Mihe. Thanks for the prompt support. I will try this code on my actual data and feedback with results. Thank you

Comment: I get an error saying "WITH is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN...
I am using Server with details:
Product: (Google) 
Version: 5.7.37-google-log 
Connector 
Version: C++ 8.0.29

Comment: Oh, MySQL 5.7 is an old version (EOL next year). Give me a 'second' to rewrite the query (might take some time).

Comment: Hope, the query given above will work (don't have 5.7 at hand).

Comment: Hi @Mihe. I get the following error message "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias." I amended your code as follows:
SELECT avg(sum_per_day) AS `Average of daily sums`
  FROM (SELECT sum(`Value`) AS sum_per_day
          FROM `source_data` s 
         WHERE `Transaction_id` = (
                 SELECT max(`Transaction_id`) 
                   FROM `source_data` 
                  WHERE date(`Date, Time`) = date(s.`Date, Time`)
                    AND client_id = s.client_id
               )
         GROUP BY date(`Date, Time`)
        ) daily_sums;

Comment: It worked. Thank you. If I want to get the prior step i.e. a  table of 
`Date, Time`     and    'sum_per_day' how do I amend the code?

Comment: Just use the inner SELECT and add the date column, e. g. SELECT date(`Date, Time`) sum(`Value`) AS sum_per_day FROM `source_data` s WHERE `Transaction_id` = ( SELECT max(`Transaction_id`) FROM source_data WHERE date(`Date, Time`) = date(s.`Date, Time`) AND client_id = s.client_id ) GROUP BY date(`Date, Time`).